# Mysql Join two tables into one output but result Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables

first table is tableA:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| NIM       | TA          |
+-----------+-------------+
| 107032014 | A_2010/2011 |
| 107032014 | B_2010/2011 |
| 107032014 | A_2011/2012 |
| 107032014 | B_2011/2012 |
| 107032014 | A_2012/2013 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

and second table is tableB:

```
+-----------+---------+-------------+
| NIM       | subtot  |     TA2     |
+-----------+---------+-------------+
| 107032014 | 6550000 | A_2010/2011 |
| 107032014 | 6550000 | B_2010/2011 |
| 107032014 | 6550000 | A_2011/2012 |
+-----------+---------+-------------+
```

how do I join two tables into one output like this :

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| NIM       | TA          | subtot      |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| 107032014 | A_2010/2011 | 6550000     |
| 107032014 | B_2010/2011 | 6550000     |
| 107032014 | A_2011/2012 | 6550000     |
| 107032014 | B_2011/2012 | 0           |
| 107032014 | A_2012/2013 | 0           |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

i used select operation : 
 
`select *,(select subtot from tableB where NIM='107032014') as subtot from tableA where NIM='107032014';` 

but :

> ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Look for JOIN...https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want with a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select subtot
        from tableB b
        where b.NIM = a.NIM and
              b.TA2 = a.TA
       ) as subtot
from tableA a
where a.NIM = '107032014';
```

Because you want `0` rather than `NULL`, you need a bit of extra work.  Here is one method:

```
select a.*,
       (select coalesce(sum(subtot), 0)
        from tableB b
        where b.NIM = a.NIM and
              b.TA2 = a.TA
       ) as subtot
from tableA a
where a.NIM = '107032014';
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `left join` by `nim` and `ta`:

```
SELECT    a.nim, a.ta, COALESCE(subtot, 0)
FROM      tablea a
LEFT JOIN tableb b ON a.nim = b.nim AND a.ta = b.ta
```